# gitignore file pattern not working

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

I have dynamic directory structure like,

```
dependency
  a
    b
  c
    d  e
  f
    g
      h
```

I want to ignore all files under dependency folder recursively except **`.xml`** files.

I am using below pattern to achieve the same.

```
dependencies/**
!dependencies/**/*.xml
```

But it seems it's not working for me. It's ignoring all the files but accepting only `.xml` files which are **directly** inside the dependency folder, **not recursively**. :(

I am using below environment.
**OS** : Windows 7(64 bit)
**Git** : 2.6.1.windows.1

Can anyone help me?

Comment: got root cause behind this, there are certain rules while **excluding** or **re-including** files. Refer : http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_notes

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

You ignore everything but white-list the parent folders.
Then you can white-list files.

```
dependencies
!dependencies/**/
!dependencies/**/*.xml
```

As I mentioned in "[How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the `gitignore` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/6309)", there is mainly one rule to remember with `.gitignore`:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**

That means, when you exclude everything ('`*`'), you have to white-list folders, before being able to white-list files.

Check if this is working with [`git check-ignore -v -- afile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to see if it is ignored (and by which rule) or not.