# How do I track only specific files using .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

What should I put in my Git repository's `.gitignore` to exclude all files and directories there *except* specific ones. For example if I have a large number of files and directories in a repo, and just want Git to track `fileX`, `.fileY`, and `directoryZ`, but completely ignore everything else, what should be in my `.gitignore`?

Comment: @s-hunter: The answer below seems a lot better than any of those (if I understand it). How do we close this as a duplicate question, but highlight that answer?

Comment: My intension is to link this question to the other one that's essential the same but worded differently. So that people can find this question and the other question using the words you used. Thus I commented it but didn't flag it.

Comment: @s-hunter: Sounds good. I'll accept this answer and mark this as solved by the duplicate so it can be closed.

Comment: None of this old answer mention the rule I mention below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/6309 is more recent and more accurate for what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ignore content; but exclude folders.
That allows you to exclude files.

```
/**
!/**/
!fileX
```

That is because:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

Check the effect of a .gitignore with [`git checkignore -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

```
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```