# git - How to ignore only one file without extension?

Tags: git, gitignore

I wish to ignore only one file without extension. 
I am able to ignore some files by names, but they all have extensions. Unfortunately I work with some files without extension that should not be ignored; thus, I can not use the solution provided here [How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023550/how-do-i-add-files-without-dots-in-them-all-extension-less-files-to-the-gitign).

Does anybody know a way to achieve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Based on this Gist https://gist.github.com/chichunchen/970a7e97c74a253a4503

Include the next 3 lines in the beginning of your .gitignore

```
# Ignore all
*
# Unignore all with extensions
!*.*
# Unignore all dirs
!*/
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

You might be making this more complex than it has to be.  This could possibly be due to the answer you cited which ignores all extensionless files.  To ignore a file without an extension does not appear to be very different than ignoring a file with an extension.  To ignore your single file without an extension add this to your `.gitignore`:

```
relative/path/to/your/file
```

If the file had an extension, you would just add this:

```
relative/path/to/your/file.ext
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before but it did not work. Right now I just noticed that because the file was already in the remote repository. It did not ignore it. I had to remove it first and then it was able to ignore it without any problems.

Comment: @cyntia Yes, if a file is already being tracked then you need to first use `git rm --cached` to remove it from the repository before adding it to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: You can use `git ls-files -i --exclude-standard` to list them first.