# How can I add my executable file to .gitignore when the file has no extension?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've created a C++ file and it runs perfectly. But the problem comes when I push my code to GitHub. There is an executable file as the result of building my C++ program, and it's being added to source control. I don't want that.

In Windows, executables have the file extension `.exe` and I can write `*.exe` in the `.gitignore`. But in Ubuntu, executables don't need an extension. How do I make Git ignore that?

Comment: Generally speaking you should not include your build output files in source-control - so why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/39409461/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+without+extension

Answer (score 7):

The `.gitignore` file does not need to use wildcards. It can match whole names as well. If your executable is named "myprog", then add a line containing `myprog` to the ignore-file.

Usually, you would have your build generate its outputs to a subdirectory: *e.g.* `bin`, and you can put that entire directory into the ignore-file as follows:

```
bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add just the name of the file in the `.gitignore` file.

**But if the file is already tracked by git** you will have in all likelihood to untrack it with:

```
git rm --cached my-file
```

Otherwise you will see that the file is not ignored. Because the `.gitignore` rules work only on untracked file.