# git ignores too many files

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have files structure:

```
$ ls xtest/
arch.gz.keep  
raq.gz.keep
qq

$ ls xtest/qq/
ww.gz.gitkeep
aa.keep
```

My `.gitignore`

```
/xtest/*
*.sql
*.gz
*.zip
*.log
!*.keep
!*.gitkeep
!*.dist
!*.dist.*
```

`git status`
files untracked:

```
xtest/.gitkeep
xtest/.keep
xtest/arch.gz.keep
```

For me i need also to have untracked:

```
xtest/qq/ww.gz.gitkeep
xtest/qq/aa.keep
```

`git --version
1.9.1 
on Ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: Have you commited your file before? If the file is in the repo it's not ignored.

Comment: No, i haven't commited any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, the point is that i want to ignore every file/path
starting from dir 'xtest' -> '/xtest/'
except some files placed anywhere in /xtest/
[How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023550/how-do-i-add-files-without-dots-in-them-all-extension-less-files-to-the-gitign)

Maybe for somebody it will help:
To ignore any file in dir `/xtest/` but not any directory and not some specific files:

```
/xtest/**/*
!/xtest/**/*/
/xtest/**/cache/*
*.sql
*.gz
*.zip
*.log
!*.keep
!*.gitkeep
!*.dist
!*.dist.*
```

subdirs of cache/ will be ignored always, even if there is *.keep, *.gitkeep, etc but not ignored in first depth into cache/ and almost all files will be ignored in other dirs (into /xtest/) except *.keep, *.gitkeep, etc

Answer (score 1):

In `qq` folder, if it’s only has `ww.gz.gitkeep` and `aa.keep` or you want all the files in `qq` folder are version controlled by git, just remove `/xtest/*` in `.gitignore`, so the `.gitignore` looks like:

```
*.sql
*.gz
*.zip
*.log
!*.keep
!*.gitkeep
!*.dist
!*.dist.*
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not the point. I need to ignore files except some specyfic ending on .gitkeep, .keep, etc in any directory under /xtest/

Answer (score 1):

By having `/xtest/*` in your `.gitignore`, you are instructing Git to ignore `xtest/qq`. It will never descend in this directory and will never notice that there is some file matching `*.keep` that you do not want to ignore. Add one of these so that `xtest/qq` is not ignored:

```
!/xtest/qq/
!/xtest/*/
```

That latter un-ignores all directories in `xtest`, the former only `qq`.