# Git is ignoring a file in a subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` file that looks like this:

```
*
!/src
!/resources
!/.gitignore
!/package.json
!/tsconfig.json
!/README.md
```

I added a file to a subdirectory in the `src` folder `src/config/mongo.ts`. However, when I try to add the file it doesn't get added:

```
git add -A
```

I have tried modifying the second line to each of the following:

```
!/src/
!/src/*
!/src/**/*
```

However it still doesn't add the file.

I have also tried adding the file directly:

```
git add src/config/mongo.ts
```

But I get the following message:

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>   src/config/mongo.ts

`git status` only shows that the `.gitignore` file has been changed. Not sure what to do to get this working.

I would like to:

- First exclude everything `*`
- Then include everything in the `src` directory (and its subdirectories)
- Then include everything in the `resources` directory (and its subdirectories)
- Then include the listed root files

Comment: Not what you are asking, but possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19023550/2988730

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is a tricky one, took me forever to figure out when I originally ran into it.

You just need to soften the initial exclusion slightly:

```
/* # instead of just *
```

Comment: That does it! `git status` finds 2 other files as well

Answer (score 2):

src folder and its subdirectories are being ignored by git

if you want to add specific file. try

```
git add --force <file-path>
```

or try these lines in gitignore

```
/*
!/src
/src/*
!/resources
!/.gitignore
!/package.json
!/tsconfig.json
!/README.md
!/src/config
```

Comment: `git add` already isn't working, which was the whole point of the question.

Comment: Did you try force add? git add --force <file-path>

Comment: @AnuragMeena don't force anything, it is a bad practice.