# Gitignore ignore bash scripts without file extension

Tags: bash, git, gitignore

I have a repository with lots of bash scripts that I want to ignore. The problem is that the bash scripts don't have a `.sh` extension, but instead have `#!/bin/bash` at the start to signify that they are bash scripts. As a result, they cannot be identified by their file name.

I have tried putting `*.sh` in my **.gitignore** (and resetting the cache), but the bash scripts are still tracked.

Is there any way I can ignore these bash scripts in my **.gitignore**?

Comment: Have you tried listing them explicitly by name?

Comment: @StephenNewell There are loads, so that would not be possible. They are scattered in all of my dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023550/how-do-i-add-files-without-dots-in-them-all-extension-less-files-to-the-gitign)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+files+without+extensions

Comment: @phd Those ignore all files without extensions, not only bash scripts without extensions.

Comment: `.gitignore` can only ignore files by name, not by content. It doesn't distinguish shell files unless shell files have specific extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Run in repo's root directory
grep -rl '^#!/bin/bash' . >> .gitignore
```

This will list all the files with bash shebang and append it to `.gitignore`